# Many to Many relationship, bridge table - How to insert duplicate primary key?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a many to many relationship between a Recipe and a Star Rating.

A Recipe may have many Star Ratings (from multiple users).
A Star Rating (1-5) may be used in many Recipes.

Therefore, I have a bridging table called RecipeStarRatings that contains a column for RecipeId, and a column for StarRatingId.

[image: Bridging table]

However, when I try to add a StarRating for a Recipe that already has a StarRating such as RecipeId:1 and StarRatingId:5, I get the violation message:

[image: Primary Key Violation]

The designer of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RecipeStarRating] (
    [RecipeId]     INT NOT NULL,
    [StarRatingId] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_RecipeStarRating] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RecipeId] ASC, [StarRatingId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_RecipeStarRating_Recipe_RecipeId] FOREIGN KEY ([RecipeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Recipe] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_RecipeStarRating_StarRating_StarRatingId] FOREIGN KEY ([StarRatingId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[StarRating] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_RecipeStarRating_StarRatingId]
    ON [dbo].[RecipeStarRating]([StarRatingId] ASC);
```

The relevant parts of the RecipeContext.cs class

```
            // Declare RecipeId and StarRatingId as primary keys for RecipeStarRating
            modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeStarRating>()              
                .HasKey(t => new { t.RecipeId, t.StarRatingId});

            // Declare many to many for RecipeStarRating
            modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeStarRating>()
                .HasOne<Recipe>(rsr => rsr.Recipe)
                .WithMany(r => r.RecipeStarRatings)
                .HasForeignKey(rsr => rsr.RecipeId);


            // Declare many to many for RecipeStarRating
            modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeStarRating>()
                .HasOne<StarRating>(rsr => rsr.StarRating)
                .WithMany(sr => sr.RecipeStarRating)
                .HasForeignKey(rsr => rsr.StarRatingId);
```

RecipeStarRating Class

```
    public class RecipeStarRating
    {
        public int RecipeId { get; set; } 
        public int StarRatingId { get; set; }
        public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
        public StarRating StarRating { get; set; }
    }
```

StarRating Class

```
    public class StarRating
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required] 
        public float Rating { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RecipeStarRating> RecipeStarRating { get; set; }
    }
```

Recipe Class

```
    public class Recipe
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Column(TypeName= "varchar(50)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(500)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(500)")]
        public string Ingredients { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(2000)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(2000)")]
        public string Instructions { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(500)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(500)")]
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }

        public ICollection<TagRecipe> TagRecipes { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RecipeStarRating> RecipeStarRatings { get; set; }
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is here.; the PK is working correctly. You don't ask a question, you just tell us you're getting an error, and the error is **literally** telling you the why it's failing. Everything is working correctly here.

Comment: The word "However", is me trying to indicate that something is happening which I don't want to happen. i.e, I don't want the violation to trigger, how can I prevent this? Have I done something wrong, etc.

Comment: *"I don't want the violation to trigger, how can I prevent this?"* Then remove the Primary Key on the columns. Though having 2 rows that are identical would likely be a design flaw.

Comment: Don't confuse the "rating" value (1-5) with the StarRatingId. Think of the StarRatingId as a meaningless key. You want to record 2 5-star ratings which means creating a new StarRating with a Rating value of 5 to associate to the recipe, not associate the same 5 star rating twice. `new` up a new StarRating with a rating value and add it to the recipe's StarRatings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create and add a *new* StarRating.  This becomes obvious when you add some more properties to the StarRating, as each StarRating is left at a different time by a different user,  eg:

```
public class StarRating
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime RatingDate {get;set;}

    public string UserName {get;set;}

    [Required] 
    public float Rating { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RecipeStarRating> RecipeStarRating { get; set; }
}
```